# How to determine if all objects in an array are connected in Swift

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, graph-theory, graph-algorithm

I have an array (`myArray`) of custom objects (`MyObject`). Each object in the array connects to at least one other object in the array (see the code below). **I'm trying to find a way to determine if all of the objects in `myArray` are connected to one another.**

```
class MyObject {
    var id: Int = 0
    var connectedIds: [Int] = []
}
```

If `myArray` contains 5 elements (`A`, `B`, `C`, `D`, `E`; `A.id` = 0, `B.id` = 1, ...), I want to determine if all five are connected in some way. Each object has an array called `connectedIds` of the `id`s of the objects it's connected to (it does not include itself).

For example, this would be valid:

```
print(A.connectedIds) // [1]
print(B.connectedIds) // [0, 2]
print(C.connectedIds) // [1, 4]
print(D.connectedIds) // [4]
print(E.connectedIds) // [2, 3]
```

...but this would not:

```
print(A.connectedIds) // [1]
print(B.connectedIds) // [0]
print(C.connectedIds) // [3, 4]
print(D.connectedIds) // [2, 4]
print(E.connectedIds) // [2, 3]
```

Viewed graphically (ignore the red circle), this is okay: [image: okay image]

But this is not: [image: not okay image]

Comment: This looks more like an algorithmic problem than a question about Swift. Here is a possible starting point for your research: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory)#Computational_aspects.

Answer (score 1):

Algorithme is based on find a route between two points, and another to check if all points can be connected (having route between them):

```
    // Find route from an object to other object
    func findNewRoute(currentRoute: inout [Int], from: Int, to: Int) {
        currentRoute.append(from)
        let connectedObjects = (objects.filter { $0.id == from }.first!).connectedIds
        for index in connectedObjects {
            if !currentRoute.contains(index) {
                findNewRoute(currentRoute: &currentRoute, from: index, to: to)
            }
        }
    }

    // Check Validation
    func checkValid(group: [MyObject]) -> Bool {
        for object in objects {
            if !(objects.filter {
                element in
                var result:[Int] = []
                findNewRoute(currentRoute: &result, from: object.id, to: element.id)
                return !result.contains(element.id)
            }).isEmpty {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a graph problem of a [connected component](https://www.wikiwand.com/en/Connected_component_(graph_theory)).

You can run the depth-first search on each node and get the connected component. If you have more than two component in the result then yes all the object is not connected to all other objects.

```
class MyObject {
  var id: Int = 0
  var connectedIds: [Int] = []
}

func isAlreadyVisited(n: MyObject, cc: inout [[MyObject]]) -> Bool {
  for c in cc {
    c.forEach {
      return ($0.id == n.id)
    }
  }
  return false
}

func connectedComponent(g: [MyObject]) -> [[MyObject]] {
  var cc = [[MyObject]]()
  for n in g {
    if !isAlreadyVisited(n: n, cc: &cc) {
      var c = DFS(n, g) // Use placeHolder for DFS, you can write your own
      cc.append(contentsOf: c)
    }
  }
  return cc
}

var cc = connectedComponent(g: [MyObject(), MyObject()])
```